# Dto projection a part only of the one to many relation

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
public class Enterprise{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enterprise",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
   private List<Person> persons;
}

@Entity
public class Person{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String firstName;
   private String lastname;
   private String email;
   private boolean principal;
   @ManyToOne
   private Enterprise enterprise;
}
```

With a jpql query, I search to get the email of the enterprise and the one of the person who are principal.